# Is it possible to make the CLR JIT use SIMD from C# in WP7?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, clr, jit

If I have, say, 4 floating point numbers that I want to multiply on Windows Phone 7, is there some way that I can write this in C# so that the CLR JIT will optimise this with an SIMD instruction?  I'm trying to get more performance out of my WP7 phone for a very calculation intensive app.

I have an HTC 7 Trophy with a Snapdragon processor which supports the NEON (Advanced SIMD) instruction set and VFPv3 floating-point extensions. I'm just trying to find out how I can make use of these.

Comment: I would be _shocked_ if this were possible.

Comment: What specific WP7 device do you have?  A lot of "mobile applications processors" have DSP co-processors, which have a lot in common with SIMD.

Comment: No one on the Microsoft forums seems to know either.  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsphone7series/thread/b6da91a4-cde6-44a5-8772-1148728c5748  I'll ask the Phone MVPs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that SIMD support is added to Windows Phone 'Mango' http://blogs.msdn.com/b/abhinaba/archive/2011/04/10/simd-support-in-netcf.aspx.

Comment: It's worth noting that it's only "targeted" support, meaning some (and only some) built-in types will get SIMD support, but no user-defined types will take advantage of it.

Comment: I added some suggestions for more general case, non Xna-specific SIMD intrinsics in the comments of that blog post.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately no. You have to rely on what the platform developers did (the kernel itself may be built to use any built-in FPU).  If the kernel isn't making use of NEON instructions, you're out of luck, even if there is support at the processor level. You cannot P/Invoke on Windows Phone, so unless the JITter already built into the phone is making those calls for you, you have no way to alter it.